# Create duplicate files on 2 different locations?

Tags: filesystems, cloning, duplicate-files

tough to find information to my idea as people normally look forward to find and remove duplicates not vice versa.

I have an application running to control a heating system.
It uses a file based database to store configuration and sensor data.
There is a backup routine implemented in the software which is running on a daily basis.

My question: is it possible to intervene from outside and clone the live output to an external storage? In case of an hardware failure would the loss of data be absolutely minimal instead of up to 24 hours.

I was hoping it would be as easy as using symbolic links.

You may wonder if it is necessary and worth the effort. Yes it is. These heating systems are of gigantic dimensions and need real-time data eg. for efficiency to keep fuel consumption as low as possible. We are talking about several ton of fuel per hour.

Cheers
Jan

Comment: Is the system connected to any network? From the outside, the outside of what?

Comment: Do you just want periodic backups with an interval less than 24h or do you want to run the backup whenever the original file changes? How high is the update rate of the original file?

Comment: I want a constant update on change.
The interval varies very much depending on the function.
Say somewhat between 1 sec and 5 min

It is in a few cases connected to a network but rather assume it is offline